# after agreeing to receive push-notification the app crashes iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

notification for my app, and i couldn't figure out, why the app crashes after the push-notification dialog. If I run the app again after the crash it will work fine, and the token will be registered in my DB

Would really appreciate your help with this problem.

Thanks in advance

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self registerPushNotification];
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    //[self loadQuestionsAnswersFromPlist];
    [Tapjoy requestTapjoyConnect:@"xxx" secretKey:@"xx" options:@{ TJC_OPTION_ENABLE_LOGGING : @(YES) } ];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];

    [self.window addSubview:_tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}


-(void) registerPushNotification {
    NSString *iOSversion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    NSString *prefix = [[iOSversion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] firstObject];
    float versionVal = [prefix floatValue];


    if (versionVal >= 8)
    {


        //for iOS8
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
         UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];


    }
    else

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

}

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)devviceToken
{
    self.deviceToken = [[[devviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    SessionData* sData = [SessionData sharedManager];
    sData.hasReceivedToken = TRUE;
    sData.token = self.deviceToken;
    if (sData.isRegistered) {
        id<MyInfoViewDelegate> myInfoVC = [[_tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        [myInfoVC saveDeviceToken:self.deviceToken];

    }
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);

}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive ||
        application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }

    NSDictionary* keys = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSString* alert = [keys objectForKey:@"alert"];
    int code = [[keys objectForKey:@"code"]intValue];
    if (code == 1) {
        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Question" message:alert delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

log

> 2014-10-07 07:26:13.603 Health Screener[145:60b] starting profile
>   request using - 2.1.17 with options: 63 2014-10-07 07:26:14.486 Health
>   Screener[145:60b] [TJLog level: 4] Tapjoy Request:
>   https://connect.tapjoy.com/connect?
>   2014-10-07 07:26:16.821 Health Screener[145:60b] Application windows
>   are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application
>   launch 2014-10-07 07:26:17.930 Health Screener[145:60b] [TJLog level:
>   4] Connect success with type:0 2014-10-07 07:26:18.197 Health
>   Screener[145:60b]
>   {"success":true,"output":{"success":true,"userid":1284,"udid":
>   2014-10-07 07:26:19.988 Health Screener[145:60b] [TJLog level: 4]
>   Events proxy is ready 2014-10-07 07:26:21.178 Health Screener[145:60b]
>   -[UINavigationController saveDeviceToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17565670 2014-10-07 07:26:21.181 Health
>   Screener[145:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController
>   saveDeviceToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17565670'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x2d7eaf83 0x37f9bccf 0x2d7ee917 0x2d7ed203 0x2d73c768 0x343c7 0x30329867 0x3032a3d5 0x3119df2f
>   0x2d7b5a67 0x2d7b5a03 0x2d7b41d7 0x2d71eebf 0x2d71eca3 0x32624663
>   0x3006b14d 0x337ed 0x384a8ab7) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

// savedevicetoken

> -(void)saveDeviceToken:(NSString*) deviceToken{
>
> ```
> self.api.requestCode = 5;     NSString *baseURL = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:SAVE_DEVICE_TOKEN];
>
> SessionData *sData = [SessionData sharedManager];
>   NSMutableString *parameters = [NSMutableString string];     [parameters appendFormat:@"uid=%d",sData.userId];   [parameters
> ```
>
> appendFormat:@"&token=%@",deviceToken];       NSLog(@"%@",parameters);
>         [self.api httpPost:baseURL withRequest:parameters]; }
>
> -(void)didFinishRequest {
>
> ```
> NSError *e = nil;
> NSDictionary *output = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [self.api.message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:
> ```
>
> NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
>       BOOL success = [[output objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];
>       if (self.api.requestCode == 1) {
>           if (success) {
>               SessionData *sData = [SessionData sharedManager];
>               sData.userId = [[[output objectForKey:@"output"] objectForKey:@"userid"] intValue];
>               sData.isRegistered = YES;
>               if (sData.hasReceivedToken) {
>                   sData.callGetAnswers = YES;
>                   [self saveDeviceToken:sData.token];
>               } else {
>                   [self getQuestionsAndAnswers];
>               }
>           } else {
>               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"You do not have internet connection,
>   try again when you have an internet connection." delegate:nil
>   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
>               [alert show];
>           }
>           return;
>       }

Comment: Please include crash logs and/or error messages

Comment: Please don't look for features by using `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`.

Comment: error message added thanks

Comment: Especially since the edit, I wholeheartedly *disagree* with the close votes / down votes. This question has an explanation of what is wrong, a code sample, expected and actual outcome. The English isn't great, but I can understand what's meant.